# Two machines, same wireless adapters, different speeds

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, internet-speed

I have two machines next to each other (within 5ft), with the same wireless adapter installed (TP/LINK USB Wireless N adapter) in each.

The wireless router is in another room. Connecting directly to the router I get 120mb/s.

From one machine (an older, slightly slower machine, running Windows 7, hereby called "Win7") I get a speedtest.net download speed of 65mb/s

From the other machine (newer, faster, running Windows 8, hereby called "Win8") I get a speedtest.net download speed of 35mb/s. Both machines get 10mb/s upload.

As far as I can see they're both set up the same, the wireless adapters are identical and both using the latest drivers from the manufacturer. All the wireless settings are the same (encryption AES, etc) as far as I can tell.

Below I've pasted the result of netsh int tcp show global on both machines

**Win8:**

```
TCP Global Parameters
----------------------------------------------
Receive-Side Scaling State          : enabled
Chimney Offload State               : enabled
NetDMA State                        : disabled
Direct Cache Access (DCA)           : disabled
Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level    : normal
Add-On Congestion Control Provider  : none
ECN Capability                      : enabled
RFC 1323 Timestamps                 : disabled
Initial RTO                         : 3000
Receive Segment Coalescing State    : disabled
```

Result of wmic NIC where NetEnabled=true get Name, Speed:

```
Name                             Speed
TP-LINK Wireless USB Adapter #2  193250000
```

**Win7:**

```
TCP Global Parameters
----------------------------------------------
Receive-Side Scaling State          : enabled
Chimney Offload State               : enabled
NetDMA State                        : enabled
Direct Cache Acess (DCA)            : disabled
Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level    : normal
Add-On Congestion Control Provider  : none
ECN Capability                      : enabled
RFC 1323 Timestamps                 : disabled
```

Result of wmic NIC where NetEnabled=true get Name, Speed:

```
Name                             Speed
300Mbps Wireless USB Adapter     58000000
```

If there's anything else I can do/post to provide more information please say, I'm not great with configuring hardware.

Thanks

Comment: When you say 'speedtest' do you mean the actual available bandwidth (eg. measured for example by iperf) or the link speed (the maximum speed at which the link can communicate)?

Comment: Ah sorry, had a typo there. I was following from the average of three readings from speedtest.net. I shall edit my question accordingly

Comment: Can you post the output of `wmic NIC where NetEnabled=true get Name, Speed`? (type it into cmd)

Comment: I've added the results in an edit. Interesting that the two devices have different names and speeds. I imagine name is to do with the drivers being different (disk didn't include win8 drivers so I had to get them from the manufacturer's site). Speed is weird though as it's higher on the slower connection. Could it be that one of them is plugged into USB 1 instead of 2 or something?

Comment: There is something wrong with your speedtest.net test. The win7 machine has a link speed of 27mbps - meaning it would be impossible for it to communicate at 65mbps over that link.

Comment: Interesting. I did another run on the win7 machine and it came back as a speed of 58,000,000. I think something might have been downloading on it when I ran the original test. Speedtest.net test is the same though

Comment: I can also confirm that the speeds come out the same on both machines using a fresh install of firefox, and the long-standing install of chrome